# HTML in ticks - Google Charts - Column

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, google-visualization

Has anyone figured out how to use html in a tick in a google chart? I am trying to add a weather icon from http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons

This is what I have tried:

```
const dailyData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dailyData.addColumn('timeofday', 'Hour');
        dailyData.addColumn('number', 'Visits');

        let mTicks = [];

        for(let i: number = 8; i <22; i++) {

            let timeofday: any = [parseFloat(parsedData[0].data[i].name[1]),0,0];

            let weatherIcon = '-';

            if(parsedData[0].data[i].weather_code > 0) {

                let weather = new WeatherFunctions(parsedData[0].data[i].weather_code).getResult();

                weatherIcon = weather.icon;
            }

            let fullString: string = `${i}:00 <br/> ${weatherIcon}`;

            dailyData.addRow([timeofday, parsedData[0].data[i].visits]);
            mTicks.push({v: timeofday, f: fullString});
        }


        const options: any = {
            allowHTML: true,
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            },

            hAxis: {
                ticks:mTicks
                ,
                title: 'Time - Weather - Temperature'
            }
        };
```

where full string = `"8:00 <i class="wi wi-day-sunny-overcast"></i>"`.

However any html in the string means that the ticks do not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the chart is built using SVG,
HTML is not supported when included in chart elements
(other than tooltips)

however, the chart provides methods that can be used to position HTML overlays

on the chart's `'ready'` event, you can use chart method --> `getChartLayoutInterface()`

the interface has a method --> `getBoundingBox()`
provide the id of a chart element, and it will return the coordinates

to get the position of the first x-axis label...

```
var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
var labelBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('hAxis#0#label#0');
```

use these coordinates to position your HTML overlay

see following working snippet,
an image is added just after each x-axis label...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Hour');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Visits');
  data.addRows([
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], 10],
    [[0, 1, 0, 0], 11],
    [[0, 2, 0, 0], 12],
    [[0, 3, 0, 0], 13],
    [[0, 4, 0, 0], 14],
    [[0, 5, 0, 0], 15],
    [[0, 6, 0, 0], 16],
    [[0, 7, 0, 0], 17],
    [[0, 8, 0, 0], 18],
    [[0, 9, 0, 0], 19],
    [[0, 10, 0, 0], 20],
    [[0, 11, 0, 0], 21],
    [[0, 12, 0, 0], 22],
    [[0, 13, 0, 0], 23]
  ]);

  // build chart ticks
  var xAxisTicks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    xAxisTicks.push({
      v: data.getValue(i, 0),
      f: data.getFormattedValue(i, 0)
    });
  }

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 60,
      left: 60,
      right: 60,
      bottom: 60
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: xAxisTicks
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

  var tickIcons = [];
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // remove old ticks
    var index = tickIcons.length;
    while (index--) {
      container.removeChild(tickIcons[index]);
      tickIcons.pop();
    }

    // add ticks
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var labelPadding = 2;
    xAxisTicks.forEach(function (tick, index) {
      var labelBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('hAxis#0#label#' + index);
      var tickIcon = document.createElement('IMG');
      tickIcon.className = 'tickIcon';
      tickIcon.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/512/star_wars/16/clone_old.png';
      tickIcon.style.left = (labelBounds.left + labelBounds.width + labelPadding) + 'px';
      tickIcon.style.top = labelBounds.top + 'px';
      tickIcons.push(container.appendChild(tickIcon));
    });
  });

  drawChart();
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}

.tickIcon {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps -- note: _erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons_ is blocked from my current location...